# How to simplify multiple condition check on data restructuring function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I am having an array like this

```
let data = [
    {
      managerName: "Surendher",
      advisorName: "Kamal",
      clientName: "Shaadi",
      clients: ["client1", "client2"],
    },
    {
      managerName: "Suresh",
      advisorName: "Kamal",
      clientName: "Nikolai",
      clients: ["client3", "client4"],
    },
    {
      managerName: "LN",
      advisorName: "Ravi",
      clients: ["client5"],
    },
  ];
```

I converted the above array into like this

```
[
  {
    "advisorName": "Kamal",
    "managerName": "Surendher",
    "clientName": "Shaadi",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "clientName": "",
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "client": "client1"
      },
      {
        "clientName": "",
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "client": "client2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "advisorName": "Kamal",
    "managerName": "Suresh",
    "clientName": "Nikolai",
    "subRows": [
      {
        "clientName": "",
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "client": "client3"
      },
      {
        "clientName": "",
        "managerName": "",
        "advisorName": "",
        "client": "client4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "advisorName": "Ravi",
    "managerName": "LN",
    "client": "client5"
  }
]
```

By using the below code, I have converted the data into the desired output.

```
let res = data.map((value) => {
    return value.clients.length > 1
      ? value.managerName
        ? {
            advisorName: value.advisorName,
            managerName: value.managerName,
            clientName: value.clientName,
            subRows: value.clients.map((_, i) => ({
              clientName: "",
              managerName: "",
              advisorName: "",
              client: value.clients[i],
            })),
          }
        : value.advisorName
        ? {
            advisorName: value.advisorName,
            clientName: value.clientName,
            subRows: value.clients.map((_, i) => ({
              clientName: "",
              advisorName: "",
              client: value.clients[i],
            })),
          }
        : {
            clientName: value.clientName,
            subRows: value.clients.map((_, i) => ({
              clientName: "",
              client: value.clients[i],
            })),
          }
      : value.managerName
      ? {
          advisorName: value.advisorName,
          managerName: value.managerName,
          clientName: value.clientName,
          client: value.clients[0],
        }
      : value.advisorName
      ? {
          advisorName: value.advisorName,
          clientName: value.clientName,
          client: value.clients[0],
        }
      : {
          clientName: value.clientName,
          client: value.clients[0],
        };
  });

  console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

But in the above function, you can see most of the code is repeated. Is there any way I could make this above function a simple one with less code?

Checking condition on managerName, advisorName, and clientName. If that present that key and value will be added or else not. And same if clients array length is more than 1 will create a subRows and do some kind of similar process.

And why I am doing this kind of structure because. I am in creating a multi-level expandable table row using `@tanstack/react-table`. For that, It requires structure like this.

Here u can get the working demo example of this https://codesandbox.io/s/tanstack-table-expansion-sub-level-goe-191pip?file=/src/App.js

Please let me know your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to reproduce the keys of the parent object in the new child object (but with empty string as value), so it would make sense to iterate the keys of this parent object dynamically, instead of checking them in a hard-coded manner:

```js
let data = [{managerName: "Surendher",advisorName: "Kamal",clientName: "Shaadi",clients: ["client1", "client2"],},{managerName: "Suresh",advisorName: "Kamal",clientName: "Nikolai",clients: ["client3", "client4"],},{managerName: "LN", advisorName: "Ravi",clients: ["client5"],},];

const result = data.map(({clients, ...obj}) =>
    clients.length < 2
      ? {...obj, client: clients[0] }
      : {...obj,
            subRows: clients.map(client =>
                Object.fromEntries(
                    Object.keys(obj).map(key => [key, ""])
                                    .concat([["client",client]])
                )
            )
        }
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. In the above function the condition check for managerName, advisorName, and clientName are missing

Comment: These checks are *implied*, that is what I wrote in the first paragraph. This code *avoids* such hardcoded checks, but takes them dynamically when they are present, and not when they are not present. Is there something not right in the output?

Answer (score 1):

Just another simplification way:

```js
const data = [{managerName: "Surendher",advisorName: "Kamal",clientName: "Shaadi",clients: ["client1", "client2"]},{managerName: "Suresh",advisorName: "Kamal",clientName: "Nikolai",clients: ["client3", "client4"]},{managerName: "LN",advisorName: "Ravi",clients: ["client5"]}];

const emptyClient = {
    clientName: "",
    managerName: "",
    advisorName: "",
};

const makeClients = (clients) => 
    clients.map((client) => ({ ...emptyClient, client }));

const transformed = data.map(({ clients, ...rest }) => {
    const subRows = (clients.length === 1)
        ? { client: clients.at(0) }
        : { subRows: makeClients(clients) };
        
    return { ...rest, ...subRows };
});

console.log(transformed);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```